# How can I normalize Lucene scores?

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene

I want to normalize the Lucene scores between specific numbers

For example, a query returns the following scores...

```
0.35773993
0.15979238
0.15305749
0.14774998
0.14689445
```

And another query returns

```
2.32223993
1.55979222
1.14705711
0.12773933
0.10689411
```

How can I normalize the scores?

Comment: What's your goal with normalization of the scores? Normalization across queries doesn't really make sense (but there's a norm factor in the scoring formula that at least introduces a part for that). Since the last query is different from the first one, the scores returned isn't comparable (i.e. the numeric value doesn't mean any specific).

Comment: Because I want to see which query is more relevant to the documents..

Comment: But those numbers won't really tell you that - how do you define that _a query_ is more relevant to documents? If it's just the one giving the highest score (since normalizing wouldn't change that, seeing as that would scale the scores within [0, 1] for [0, max] instead), just pick that one. But that number doesn't really tell you that a query is more relevant (.. which would mean exactly what?) to the document.